# Unable to run RoR app (Fedena) on Apache2 via Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, fedena

First of all I would like to extend my gratitude to you for your help for the needy. May God bless you all.

I am trying to host a **RoR** application on *Apache* on an internal web server in our school.
The configuration is as follows:

- Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 64-bit edition.
- Apache2
- Passenger for Apache
- PHP5
- MySQL
- Ruby 1.8.7
- Rails 2.3.5

I could run the RoR application(*Fedena*) on *Webrick* without any issues (ie. via script/server command) However when I try to run *Fedena* on *Apache* via *Passenger*, it throws the error "uninitialized constant Authorization".

Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot of the error]
http://i46.tinypic.com/mj67v7.png

I would be glad if you could help me with this.

Comment: You seem to have a problem in `config/environment.rb` line 6. Can you post the file content please? 
Did you install all gems needed?

Comment: config/environment.rb `require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')

RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|

  config.time_zone = 'UTC'
  
  config.gem 'declarative_authorization', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org'
  
  config.load_once_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/lib )
  
  config.load_paths += Dir["#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/*"].find_all { |f| File.stat(f).directory? }
  
  config.reload_plugins = true if RAILS_ENV =="development"
  
  config.plugins = [:paperclip,:all]

end`

Comment: Thanks @CupraR_On_Rails here is the content of environment.rb on pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/2GmsdjWM)

Answer (score 3):

**Thanks everyone...**
I figured it out with your help.

I added the following code at the bottom of **config/boot.rb**

```
  class Rails::Boot
  def run
    load_initializer

    Rails::Initializer.class_eval do
      def load_gems
        @bundler_loaded ||= Bundler.require :default, Rails.env
      end
    end

    Rails::Initializer.run(:set_load_path)
  end
end
```

I followed the instructions in the bundler with rails 2.3 [instructions](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/rails23.html)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of possibilities, make sure you are using the proper version of the gem which is compatible with 1.8.2 and also try "bundle install" once. I feel you have used devise gem which has got compatible issue with 1.8.2. Kindly install proper gem version and also add the same to your same gem version to Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks @JeevanDongre I did a bundle install, and it returns success.. However I still can't access the app via passenger.. The app works fine via Webrick.

Comment: *** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
bundler (1.2.3)
daemon_controller (1.1.1)
declarative_authorization (0.5.6, 0.5.1)
fastthread (1.0.7)
fattr (2.2.1)
i18n (0.4.2)
mysql (2.9.0, 2.8.1)
passenger (3.0.19)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
rush (0.6.8)
session (3.1.0)

Comment: @Shaamil some people have reported the bug in the forums, check this link http://projectfedena.org/forum/12-bugs/topics/524-uninitialized-constant-authorization